# What is the significance of PIDS_PER_CPU_DEFAULT?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, kernel, limit, cpu

What is the significance of PIDS_PER_CPU_DEFAULT and define PIDS_PER_CPU_MIN defined in linux/threads.h?
I know the maximum value of PIDs can be increased to approx 4 million and the default value is 32768, but I am not able to correlate max pid value to  PIDS_PER_CPU_DEFAULT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments give a pretty good explanation:

[**include/linux/threads.h**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/threads.h#L36)

```c
/*
 * Define a minimum number of pids per cpu.  Heuristically based
 * on original pid max of 32k for 32 cpus.  Also, increase the
 * minimum settable value for pid_max on the running system based
 * on similar defaults.  See kernel/pid.c:pidmap_init() for details.
 */
#define PIDS_PER_CPU_DEFAULT    1024
#define PIDS_PER_CPU_MIN        8
```

[**kernel/pid.c**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/pid.c#L584)

```c
void __init pidmap_init(void)
{
    /* Veryify no one has done anything silly */
    BUILD_BUG_ON(PID_MAX_LIMIT >= PIDNS_HASH_ADDING);

    /* bump default and minimum pid_max based on number of cpus */
    pid_max = min(pid_max_max, max_t(int, pid_max,
                            PIDS_PER_CPU_DEFAULT * num_possible_cpus()));
    pid_max_min = max_t(int, pid_max_min,
                            PIDS_PER_CPU_MIN * num_possible_cpus());
    pr_info("pid_max: default: %u minimum: %u\n", pid_max, pid_max_min);
    .
    .
```

At init time, they are adjusting the `"default and minimum pid_max based on number of cpus"`.

The maximum number of pids you'd want running in the system depends on the number of CPUs available. (I suppose two CPUs can theoretically run twice as many concurrent processes as one CPU, with the ~same efficiency.)  Since the number of CPUs may change from boot to boot, `pid_max` is adjusted at kernel init time.

Comment: @ Jonathan. Here is the summary of what I have understood.
Max possible of PIDs in a system are ~4million but the default value is 32768. But depending on number of CPUs in a system this value (32768) gets reconfigured. For example for a single CPU system the default value of PIDs is 32768, Default PIDs per CPU allowed are 1024 and MIN PIDs per CPU allowed are 8.